# Using MySQL & Regex to extract colours from descriptions

Tags: mysql, regex

Please see the following MySQL fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e84a6a/3/0

I've included two example tables, the 1st is a list of colours, and the 2nd is a list of descriptions.

I'd like to extract colours in to a new separate column where the colour exists in both the tbl_colours & the description of tbl_example.

I suspect I need to implement regex and word boundaries (i.e. only extract colours if they match on "whole words" i.e. surrounded by white space, end/start of string, brackets etc.

What i can't get my head round is how i can combine a join and a regex with word boundaries.

Is this possible in MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you account for the bizzare notation for \b in MySQL, this was actually quite easy:

```
SELECT 
    d.Code, d.Description, c.colour
FROM
    tbl_example d
        LEFT JOIN
    tbl_colours c ON UPPER(d.Description) REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]', colour, '[[:>:]]')
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick:

```
SELECT d.Code, d.Description, c.colour
FROM tbl_example d
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT colour FROM tbl_colours) c ON d.Description REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]',colour, '[[:>:]]');
```

Comment: Hi Shay, thank you very much for the answer, unfortunately this method has a few issues. i.e. if the description contains the colour as part of another word, i.e. "red" can be found in "wired" you get false positives. This is why regex /b (word boundaries) are needed i think, but i cant get my head round it.